# Swift button callback in tableview cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures

I want to have a `UIButton` inside my `TableViewCell` and I tried it with a `closure` but it is not doing anything:

**`Cell`:**

```
let favouriteButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
    v.setImageTintColor(.darkCustom)
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favouriteButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

var favouriteButtonTappedCallback: (() -> ())?

@objc func favouriteButtonTapped() {
    self.favouriteButtonTappedCallback?()
}
```

**`CellForRowAt:`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchBarCell.reuseID) as! SearchBarCell
    
    cell.favouriteButtonTappedCallback = {
        print("tapped")
    }
    return cell
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This should work fine.

Comment: @Manav thats what I was thinking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.. I called `self.addSubView(favouriteButton` so the `contentView` actually covered the button. Simply fixed it by calling this:

```
contentView.addSubview(favouriteButton)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That's helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias FavouriteButtonTappedCallback = () -> Void   
var favouriteButtonTappedCallBack = FavouriteButtonTappedCallBack?


 if let tappedClosure = self.favouriteButtonTappedCallback {
            tappedClosure()
        }
```

and

```
cell.favouriteButtonTappedCallBack
```

Comment: and check your delegate setting, other ones looks fine

Comment: which delegates do you mean ? I set tableView.delegate and dataSource

Comment: yes @Chris as I understand your VC not subclass of TableViewVC

Comment: I have it like this: `extension CommunityViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: wherever you use tableview datasource and delegate you should reference to your delegate
vc.delegate = self for example

Comment: I have. The cells are being displayed just fine. But the button is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check all view hierarchies and make userinteraction enabled for all, this could be primary suspect.

Comment: I can select a row, so I dont think thats the issue :/

Comment: Have you set button's interaction enabled to true?